# Temporizing User Agent rotation in Scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am writing a crawlspider using Scrapy and I use a downloader middleware to rotate user agents for each request. What I would like to know if there is a way to temporize this. In other words, I would like to know if it is possible to tell the spider to change User Agent every X seconds. I thought that, maybe, using the DOWNLOAD_DELAY setting to do this would do the trick.

Answer (score 3):

You might approach it a bit differently. Since you have control over the requests/sec crawling speed via `CONCURRENT_REQUESTS`, `DOWNLOAD_DELAY` and other relevant settings, you might just count how many requests in a row would go with the same User-Agent header.

Something along these lines (based on [`scrapy-fake-useragent`](https://github.com/alecxe/scrapy-fake-useragent)) (not tested):

```
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

class RotateUserAgentMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        # let's make it configurable
        self.rotate_user_agent_freq = settings.getint('ROTATE_USER_AGENT_FREQ')

        self.ua = UserAgent()

        self.request_count = 0
        self.current_user_agent = self.ua.random

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        if self.request_count >= self.rotate_user_agent_freq:
            self.current_user_agent = self.ua.random 
            self.request_count = 0
        else:
            self.request_count += 1

        request.headers.setdefault('User-Agent', self.current_user_agent)
```

This might be not particularly accurate since there also could be retries and other reasons that can theoretically screw up the count - test it please.

Comment: This is a smart way to look at it but I am interested in the number of seconds, not in the number of requests.

Comment: @Simus thanks, these two numbers are actually related to each other depending on your settings. I was hoping you might correlate the numbers and calculate which requests count to set..

Comment: I see what you are saying here. How would you do that programmatically? I would need to calculate the time it takes for a request.